# Trouble Interpreting a Line of Code

Tags: java

I am very new to Java, and I was getting help from a teacher's assistant on my program. He really overcomplicated my code, although it works, and I am having trouble understanding what he did to it. My main confusion comes down to this one line, which uses string.toCharArray (something we have not covered in class). I could not find any sites online that explained it in terms that I could understand, so if anyone could tell me what it means, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!!

```
for (char ch : variableName.toCharArray())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a variable named `variableName`. And let's say that variable was a string.

The `.toCharArray()` will take your variable, your string, and turn it into an array of individual characters. Those characters are of the `char` type.

The for loop, will allow you to iterate over each `char` in your new array. Effectively loop over every character in your original string.

Comment: So basically it breaks the string up into individual characters, and allows me to perform an action on each one as long as the for loop still goes?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically, your professor has taken a `String` variable and called the `toCharArray()` method on it which return a `char[]` where each index is filled with each character from your word/sentence/String.

This is more than often used to iterate over each single character of a `String`, which is what is done here by your professor.

---

### Example

```
String myName = "Yassin";

for (char c : myName.toCharArray()){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

will print each of the characters within my name on a line :

```
Y
a
s
s
i
n
```

Answer (score 0):

From **@JavaDoc**:

```
/**
 * Converts this string to a new character array.
 *
 * @return  a newly allocated character array whose length is the length
 *          of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain
 *          the character sequence represented by this string.
 */
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

1. Method `toCharArray()` divide you string by single char and add them one by one in to array.
2. Loop `for() {}` will iterate through all chars in newly created array, so you no need to think about: array lenght, iterator etc.